# Linq to Entities, select parent entities with child entities, where child entities match condtion

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I just can't seem to find an example that does what I need.

I have entities "Person", and "SavedSearch". These are joined correctly with foreign keys, so navigation properties work. A "Person" can include multiple "SavedSearch" entities.

What I want to do, is select a list of all of the "Person" entities, each with a collection of "SavedSearch" entities, where these SavedSearch entities meet a particular condition.

This is the closest I've been able to get...

```
Dim person_query = From p In db.Person
                   Where p.SavedSearch.Any(Function(s) s.SendEmails = True)
                   Select New SavedSearchDetails With {
                     .PersonID = p.PersonID,
                     .SavedSearchList = p.SavedSearch.Where(Function(s) s.SendEmails = True)
                   }
```

This gives me the correct results, but it seems incorrect having to specify the where condition twice. Checking the SQL generated, I can see that it's using left outer joins, which I don't think should be necessary.

So essentially what I need is a list of "Person" entities, with a list of "SavedSearch" entities, where "SendEmail" is true.

Also I should add. I'm only wanting the "Person" entities if they include the matching "SavedSearch" child entities.

Comment: You really ought to use plural names for collections and singular names only for properties that return a single entity.  `db.Person` should be `db.People` or `db.Persons` and `p.SavedSearch` should be `p.SavedSearches`.  Type, member and variable names should be as self-documenting as possible so a plural name should always be used to indicates an array or collection.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney In this case, I just had VS create the model from the existing database, using the default settings, and this is what it came up with. I'll keep this in mind though for future projects.

Comment: Pluralising collection names is one of the options when using database-first.  You should examine all the options available to you in such cases. You can still re-run the wizard and have it make changes and you can also change entity or property names in the designer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq2Entities Equivalent Query for Parent/Child Relationship, With All Parents and Children, Filtering/Ordering Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369477/linq2entities-equivalent-query-for-parent-child-relationship-with-all-parents-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Include` method to include child entities in the query result:

```
Dim peopleWithDavedSearches = From p In db.Person.Include("SavedSearch")
                              Where p.SavedSearch.Any(Function(s) s.SendEmails)
                              Select p
```

Each `Person` object in `peopleWithDavedSearches` will then have its `SavedSearch` property populated if there are any entities to populate it with.

You may also be able todo this:

```
Dim peopleWithDavedSearches = From p In db.Person.Include(Function(person) person.SavedSearch)
                              Where p.SavedSearch.Any(Function(s) s.SendEmails)
                              Select p
```

I'm not 100% sure whether standard LINQ to Entities offers that functionality these days or you still need an additional reference but you can try it and see.

Note that, if you want to include children of children then you just use dot notation, e.g.

```
From item In list.Include("Child.GrandChild.GreatGrandChild")
```

If you want to include descendents on multiple branches then you just call `Include` more than once, e.g.

```
From item In list.Include("Child1").Include("Child2")
```

Comment: Actually I realised this isn't quite what I need. This is correctly filtering "Person". However the child collection "SaveSearch" still includes all items, whether "SendEmails" is true or not. I'd like to somehow also filter the child collection based on "SendEmails" being true. Can this be done.

Comment: You can't do that by query for `Person` entities. You'd have to filter the `SavedSearch` collections after the fact or else query for `SavedSearch` entities in the first place and include the related `Person`. That second option will give you duplicate `Person` entities though.  Basically, you can't do what you want with just a single query.